# Realization of module on JS (preferably using JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On main page banners-links. How to realize hover effect such like that? Could anyone help me with this? Link to module: [Module on site zepter.com](http://www.zepter.com/)

Comment: You'll need to try to implement it, and if that fails, post the code you have tried to use, what the exact problem is, and then someone will gladly help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this is what youre looking for?

http://www.jsonenglish.com/projects/flex/

Comment: Thank you, for your link! That's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "Element" ).hover( function() {
 // some code
});
```

Why would you want to use jquery instead of CSS however. Just use (this) to change the properties as you wish.

Comment: no, I wanted especially effect of hover as in Zepter.com